# Does electroplating with copper takes less time than electroplating with zinc?

Tags: electrochemistry, electroplating

is electroplating with copper quicker than electroplating with zinc -- assuming that in both scenerios the cathode is steel, the surface area, the current, the thickness are the same, and the electrolyte is either zinc sulfate or copper sulfate? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an old saying "It can be quick, good and cheap. But not all at the same time."  Seriously, it depends much more on used particular technology than on used metal. There are dozens or hundreds of possible surface preparations, electrolyte compositions, geometry of the cell, used current densities..... Some are faster or better than others. You would have to compare particular techniques. But if everything is the same, plating by Zn is slightly faster (Zn molar mass, density)// More seriously, do not use StackExchange as an alternative to search engines. Do your search before asking.